# Convert different formats to uncompressed audio c#

Tags: c#, .net, audio

Just wondering if anyone can recommend a .NET library that converts audio formats to uncompressed in C#? If there is no .NET library a C library will work as well. I am writing an application that requires an uncompressed audio sample.

Thanks for your help, 
Ben

Comment: it would help a lot if you gave examples of what formats you want to convert - e.g. MP3, G.711, OGG, WMA, Speex, M4A etc, since there is no one solution that will do them all

Comment: I am trying to get a 30 second grab of an M4A file and convert that to a PCM sample. Do you know if this is possible with NAudio? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm afraid not, unless you have an appropriate ACM codec on your PC that can decode m4a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples of how to use C# libraries to convert audio from one format to another:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Aumplib.aspx

http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx

[Change Audio Format in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963663/change-audio-format-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

[How to convert compressed sound stream to PCM uncompressed stream in .NET](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx#tip107)

```
DsReader dr = new DsReader("sample.amr");
IntPtr formatPcm = dr.ReadFormat();
byte[] dataPcm = dr.ReadData();
dr.Close();
```